# How do I gracefully handle this exception in a background thread in a Windows service?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, exception

I'm using C# .NET 4.0.

I have a Windows service.  This Windows service spins up a background thread. This background thread makes P/Invoke calls to a Win32 API, and very intermittently (on the order of once or twice in a 24 hour period with 1-second intervals,) the Win32 function will return garbage. I do my best to try and handle this garbage without raising an exception, but eventually an exception will occur anyway. And when it does, it terminates my service even though I am using a try/catch that catches the exception.

```
using System.Security.Principal;

Thread awesomeThread;

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{  
    ThreadStart awesomeThreadThreadStart = new ThreadStart(AwesomeThread);
    awesomeThread = new Thread(awesomeThreadThreadStart);
    awesomeThread.IsBackground = true;
    awesomeThread.Start();
}

private void AwesomeThread()
{
    while (serviceStarted)
    {
         if (serviceStarted)
             Thread.Sleep(1000)
         else
             break;

        //
        // WinApi calls happen here. Once every few hours, they return gibberish.
        //
        NTAccount account = new NTAccount(domain, username);
        SecurityIdentifier sid = null;
        try
        {
             sid = (SecurityIdentifier)account.Translate(typeof(SecurityIdentifier));                       
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
             Eventlog.WriteEntry("Oh no an exception occurred: " + ex.Message);
        }
        // Resource cleanup stuff
    }
}
```

So when an exception does occur on `account.Translate()`, the exception is caught and the event log message is written at which point it *would* be safe for the thread to continue executing... but .NET kills it, and thus, my service. Can I handle the exception and allow the background thread to keep executing?

Currently, as a workaround I have set the Windows service to automatically restart itself in the Service Controller, so I can deal with the service restarting itself once or twice a day, but I'd rather prevent it if I could.

Comment: You may want to put the try catch around everything in the while loop.  Also I would generally log exceptions using the .ToString() method instead of .Message.  You will get much more detailed information about the exception.  In addition to this make sure you deploy the pdb file with the dll/exe you are deploying to make sure line numbers are being included in your exception details.  If the exception isn't being caught is it possible you don't have the try catch around everything you need to?

Comment: @ColeW Thank you for your feedback, but I already know what the precise exception is - I don't need any more detail on what the exception is or where it's occurring or why it's happening. The exception only occurs at the single statement that I have enclosed in a try block. What I don't understand is why, even when I catch the exception, *after* the code in the catch block runs, the thread and the entire process still terminate.

Comment: We've encountered something similar using the third party libraries of a very large ERP System Appliation Provider. All of a sudden an error occurs, which can't be caught, but is logged in the event log. After that, the service just quits. After many unsuccessful hours of trying to workaround, we provided a second service that just monitors and restarts the first. This may not solve your problem, but maybe you don't feel that alone anymore...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really an answer, more a comment, but I hate the poor formatting of code in comments.

Are you 100% sure the exception in that one statement is your only problem? I'm suggesting you add the following to your program:

```
     // Create AppDomain ProcessExit and UnhandledException event handlers
     AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += CurrentDomain_ProcessExit;
     AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
```

and, of course, the event handlers:

```
  /// <summary>
  /// Method called when the process is exiting.
  /// </summary>
  private static void CurrentDomain_ProcessExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     // do some logging?
  }


  /// <summary>
  /// Method called if an unhandled AppDomain exception occurs.
  /// </summary>
  private static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender,
                                                       UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
  {
     // do some logging?
  }
```

You can't save the service at this point, but you might get some useful information.

Edit:

Just noticed I copy-and-pasted some code where the event handlers are marked "static", but that isn't necessary.

Comment: Thanks - I am going to try this... but since I can't reproduce the exception on demand it may take me a day or two to report back.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Windows Event Log to see if there are any errors reported by .NET at the time the process exits. That will often provides useful info about why a process died.